# About destroying the [environment]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burnination

I just noticed that we have an [environment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environment) tag. It's used on 12 questions, 11 of which are ID questions (ten [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) and one [episode-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episode-identification)), the last one being [Where does the water to transform Dune into a non-desert planet come from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100414/31394) The tag wiki excerpt says:

> Works focused on the care and protection of planetary environments and how protection of such an environment might impact the lives of inhabitants of that planetary environment.

It's the usual question: **do we need this tag? and if so, how should it be used?**

<sub>(Note that if the consensus is to nuke it, then this can be done with only *two* edits - both on questions which probably need tag edits anyway - followed by a moderator tag-merge. So "messing up the front page" considerations don't apply.)</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by a tag merge?

Comment: @Gallifreyan Merging [tag:environment] into [tag:story-identification], after retagging the two outlying questions. This would silently remove the environment tag from the ten story-ID questions and have no other effect on the system.

Comment: Can you then remove it from synonyms, so that it doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: @Gallifreyan When merging, we can choose whether to synonymise or not. This would definitely be a case for not synonymising.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Nuke it.**

It seems like tag that would get misused a lot even with a proper tag-wiki. IMO the current tag-wiki is a bit specific and almost seems like a Worldbuilding.SE description.

Overall it does not seem like a useful tag.

Comment: Yes, nuke the environment.

Comment: Oh, [that joke had already been done](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38477490#38477490).